# How to get Column Data types of particular table in SSAS using MDX

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssas

I have a query where I'm getting all tables and column names, but how to get Data Types and length values of columns of particular table?

```
SELECT [CATALOG_NAME] as [DATABASE],
      CUBE_NAME AS [CUBE],[DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME] AS [DIMENSION],
      LEVEL_CAPTION AS [ATTRIBUTE],
      [LEVEL_NAME_SQL_COLUMN_NAME] AS [ATTRIBUTE_NAME_SQL_COLUMN_NAME],
      [LEVEL_KEY_SQL_COLUMN_NAME] AS [ATTRIBUTE_KEY_SQL_COLUMN_NAME]
FROM $system.MDSchema_levels
WHERE CUBE_NAME  ='Adventure Works'
AND level_origin=2
AND LEVEL_NAME <> '(All)'
order by [DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME]
```

Comment: can anyone help me out regarding this I'm unable to move forward

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is `$SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_PROPERTIES`.

The query would probably be somewhat like :

```
select [HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME], [LEVEL_UNIQUE_NAME], DATA_TYPE 
from $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_PROPERTIES 
where [Dimension_Unique_Name] = '[Accident Cause]'
and [Property_Name] = 'MEMBER_VALUE'
and [CUBE_NAME] = 'Adventure Works'
```

To understand what the values in column `DATA_TYPE` mean, refer this [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146026.aspx).

Comment: yeah I have already gone through it but it is showing same data type to all columns i.e 130